# How to use GeoPandas Spatial Index with lines?

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas

I am trying to find the nearest line to a bunch of points (about 24 billion points, 4 million lines). The points exist in one GeoDataFrame, while the lines exist in another. I tried to follow this: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/140, and did this:

```
lines_sidx = lines_df['geom'].sindex
[list(lines_sidx.intersection((points.loc[i,'geom'].y, points.loc[i,'geom'].x))) for i in range(len(points))]
```

And this just returns an empty list of lists. What is going on here?

(Note that I am applying this to the first 100 lines and points from both datasets).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is prefaced with the context that you're trying to perform a nearest neighbor query, but your question itself asks about what's going on in that geopandas intersection code block. I'll try to address your question rather than its preface, as they seem to be at odds. It looks like your intersection code logic is off. The gist of using rtree with a spatial intersection is you first find the possible matches (some false positives, but no false negatives) with your index, and then you find the precise matches.

Something like this, as demonstrated in this [geopandas r-tree tutorial](http://geoffboeing.com/2016/10/r-tree-spatial-index-python/):

```
spatial_index = gdf.sindex
possible_matches_index = list(spatial_index.intersection(polygon.bounds))
possible_matches = gdf.iloc[possible_matches_index]
precise_matches = possible_matches[possible_matches.intersects(polygon)]
```

If you're attempting to do a nearest-neighbor search with a set of points and a set of lines, it's possible none of the features intersect, which could return your empty set results.